# Is it possible to force resume a sleeping thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Is it possible to force resume a sleeping thread which has been paused? For example, by calling `sleep`:

```
std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(60 * 20));
```

I know that I can communicate between threads using `std::sync::mpsc` but if the thread is asleep, this does not force it to wake up before the time indicated.

I have thought that using `std::sync::mpsc` and maybe
`Builder` and `.name` associated with the thread, but I do not know how to get the thread to wake up.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but `sleep()` is not supposed to do that anyway. If you want to be woken up, you should do a blocking wait on something like a channel or a mutex. When you say `recv()` on a channel that is empty, the calling thread will block until the channel is not empty anymore. There is basically no difference between a blocking wait and calling `sleep()` (except, of course, that the wait might be woken up).

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt My English is not very good, but if I understand correctly what it says, it is possible that using `let mut result = rx.recv().unwrap();` Could be an alternative, but could not use `thread::sleep` In that thread, to determine how long it will be asleep by default, or until an action occurs in my program. But if, I could create a function that controls when sent by the channel, when a certain time elapses, and also that it sends through the channel when the action that activates the thread occurs. If can not wake up a thread, I think that what was commented could be a alternati

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt thanks for comment

Comment: I added a complete answer with example now. I hope this explains most of your questions ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to be woken up by an event, `thread::sleep()` is not the correct function to use, as it's not supposed to be stopped.

There are other methods of waiting while being able to be woken up by an event (this is usually called *blocking*). Probably the easiest way is to **use a channel together with [`Receiver::recv_timeout()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout)**. Often it's also sufficient to send `()` through the channel. That way we just communicate a signal, but don't send actual data.

If you don't want to wake up after a specific timeout, but *only* when a signal arrives, just use [`Receiver::recv()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv).

---

Example with timeout:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, RecvTimeoutError};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            match receiver.recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(2)) {
                Err(RecvTimeoutError::Timeout) => {
                    println!("Still waiting... I'm bored!");
                    // we'll try later...
                }
                Err(RecvTimeoutError::Disconnected) => {
                    // no point in waiting anymore :'(
                    break;
                }
                Ok(_) => {
                    println!("Finally got a signal! ♥♥♥");
                    // doing work now...
                }
            }
        }
    });

    loop {
        let mut s = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut s).expect("reading from stdin failed");
        if s.trim() == "start" {
            sender.send(()).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the second thread is woken up at least every two seconds (the timeout), but also earlier once something was sent through the channel.

Answer (score 1):

`park_timeout` allows timed sleeps with wakeups from `unpark`, but it can also wake up early.

See [std::thread module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/index.html#blocking-support-park-and-unpark)

Comment: Thanks, park was the best choice in my case